# No effect of batch_size on number of iterations in model.fit in keras

Tags: keras

I have a simple model for demonstration:

```
input_layer = Input(shape=(100,))
encoded = Dense(2, activation='relu')(input_layer)

X = np.ones((1000, 100))
Y = np.ones((1000, 2))
print(X.shape)

model = Model(input_layer, encoded)
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam')
model.fit(x=X, y=Y, batch_size = 2)
```

Output is:

```
2.2.4
(1000, 100)
Epoch 1/1
1000/1000 [==============================] - 3s 3ms/step - loss: 1.3864
```

Why there are 1000 iterations in one epoch(as shown in the output).
I tried changing this but does not changes the output. I guess it should have been 1000/2 = 500. Please explain what is wrong with my understanding and how can i set the batch size appropriately.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `model.fit` the numbers in the left part of the progress bar count samples, so it is always the current samples / total number of samples.

Maybe you are confused because it works different in `model.fit_generator`. There you actually see iterations or batches being counted.

Answer (score 1):

It changes the batch size, the bar progresses faster although you do not explicitly see it as a step. I had the same question in my mind some time ago.

If you want to explicitly see each step, you can use `steps_per_epoch` and `validation_steps`.

An example is listed below.

```
model.fit_generator(training_generator,
                        steps_per_epoch=steps_per_epoch,
                        epochs=epochs,
                        validation_data=validation_generator,
                        validation_steps=validation_steps)
```

In this case, steps_per_epoch = number_of_training_samples / batch_size, while validation_steps = number_of_training_samples / batch_size.

During the training, you will see 500 steps instead of 1000 (provided that you have 1000 training samples and your batch_size is 2).